# Сделать долгой загрузку страницы

Tags: php, html

Нужно сделать страницу так, чтоб грузилась очень долго, но не знаю как  ето зделать, помогите.

Comment: всё на самом деле зависит от того, какие конкретно цели вы преследуете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно инициировать задержку с помощью функции [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php):

```
sleep(10);  // 10-секундная задержка
/*
код скрипта
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

В Chrome DevTools есть специальный инструмент для тестирования веб-приложений в условиях медленной сети или даже оффлайн.

Называется он "Network Throttling"

- Нажимаете F12, вкладка Network/Сеть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Недавно узнал, как можно [посылать ответ частями (chunk)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Скрипт ниже отправляет содержимое в браузер частями, с задержкой `$sleepTimeMs`.

Если отправить текстовый файл, он будет показываться в браузере, постоянно "расти", получая новые порции данных.

При отправке бинарного файла-картинки с прогрессивным сжатием она будет отрисовываться:

[image: прогрессивное сжатие]

Скрипт `slow.php`:

```
// локальный файл, который будем посылать в браузер. можно передавать бинарные данные
$localFile = __DIR__ . '/../data/top1000.json';

// задержка перед отправкой следующей части, мс
$sleepTimeMs = 500000;

// размер части, должен совпадать с размером буферной зоны PHP
$chunkSize = (int)ini_get('output_buffering');

$file = fopen($localFile, "r");

header("Transfer-encoding: chunked");
header("Content-Encoding: none");
flush();

while(!feof($file)) {
  $chunk = fread($file, $chunkSize);
  // размер части
  printf("%x\r\n", strlen($chunk));
  // часть
  echo $chunk . "\r\n";
  // отправляем содержимое в браузер
  flush();
  usleep($sleepTimeMs);
}
fclose($file);

// завершаем передачу, если не выполнить, curl выдаст такую ошибку:
// curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
echo "0\r\n\r\n";
flush();

// Все что ниже, не будет получено браузером, но веб-сервер, по-идее, эту часть также отправит:
// die('Эта часть не будет загружена');
```

Чтобы детально рассмотреть ответ сервера, выполните:

```
curl --raw -k --verbose -i http://{ваш-сайт}/slow.php > /tmp/response.txt
less /tmp/response.txt
```

Выглядеть будет так

[image: chunked]

### Ссылки

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481858/how-to-make-php-generate-chunked-response